# Angular reactive form *ngFor loop, cannot read 'property' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r4g6uv?file=src/app/personal/personal.component.html) example

I'm trying to loop dynamic values to create radio button items on my form. I have managed to display the three radio buttons coming from my data:

```
radiot: [
        {
          section: "yes",
          sectionCode: "1"
        },
        {
          section: "no",
          sectionCode: "2"
        },
        {
          section: "maybe",
          sectionCode: "3"
        }
      ]
```

The problem is I cant display the option of "section".

e.g.

```
<div class="form-check-inline" *ngFor="let item of personal.radioButtons.radiot; let i = index">

    <label for="yes" class="col-12 customradio"
        ><span>{{item[i].section}}</span>
        <input value="{{item[i].section}}" id="{{item[i]}}" type="radio" [formControlName]="i"/>
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? getting the error - `Cannot read property 'section' of undefined`

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r4g6uv?file=src/app/personal/personal.component.html) example

Comment: `i` is the index into `personal.radioButtons.radiot` that would give you the current `item`, so it's unclear what you expect from `item[i]`. That would be e.g. `{ section: "yes", sectionCode: "1" }[0]`, hence `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your template from **[formControlName]** to **formControlName**

```
        <label for="{{item.section}}" class="col-12 customradio"
            ><span>{{item.section}}</span>
            <input value="{{item.section}}" name="formGroupName" id="{{item.section}}" type="radio" formControlName="radiot"/>
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
```

As it is currently written you were telling angular to look for a **variable** named radiot which is undefined, but what it needs is a **string** so it can look for it as a property on the current form object

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `i` in *ngFor you already have reference to the object at that position.

So for the first iteration your `item` would be

```
{
          section: "yes",
          sectionCode: "1"
}
```

So you can just do `item.section` - no need for the index position.

```
<span>{{item.section}}</span>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks, yes I changed this but values only appear when selected and remain checked.

Answer (score 0):

You should put `=` instead of `:`

```
radiot = [
  {
    section: "yes",
    sectionCode: "1"
  },
  {
    section: "no",
    sectionCode: "2"
  },
  {
    section: "maybe",
    sectionCode: "3"
  }
];
```